# How can I store radiobutton values in an array in the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I am trying to get numerous radiobutton values from multiple fxmlcontroler files (each fxml has one group of 5 radiobuttons... user will select one) and store them in an array in the main method. How do I use the ToggleGroup to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have come up with a solution. First you must place the desired radio buttons innto a togglegroup:

```
    final ToggleGroup tg1 = new ToggleGroup();
    g1b1.setToggleGroup(tg1);
    g1b2.setToggleGroup(tg1);
    g1b3.setToggleGroup(tg1);
    g1b4.setToggleGroup(tg1);
    g1b5.setToggleGroup(tg1);
```

next, add a listener:

```
tg1.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>()
```

add the radio buttons into an array:

```
            Object[] rba = tg1.getToggles().toArray();
```

use a loop to find the selected radio button:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rba.length; i++){
                if(tg1.getSelectedToggle() == rba[i]){
                    System.out.println("SELECTED RADIO BUTTON" + i);
                }else{
                    System.out.println(rba[i].toString());
                }
            }
```

I did this with one document controller. you surely can find a way to what you need from here